Looking for urban fantasy book (maybe young adult) where a boy turns a bridge into a forest
Medium: book
Language: English (US)
Year:  read this in a library between 1997ish and 2003ish.
Genre: Urban fantasy (possibly young adult)
Plot:
There is a group of kids living in a library (I think). There has been some sort of world-wide devastation and occasionally more kids join the collective. Each of them gets a new name that is "nature-y" like Birch or Sparrow. In fact, I think a girl is renamed Sparrow because she has a tendency to flit around.
The main story centers around this one boy who starts getting magical powers that makes things grow.
I cannot remember if the antagonist is just another group, but I seem to remember that it was headed by an adult woman who is trying to get people to stop joining this boy's group.
The big deal towards the end of the book is that the boy is leading everyone somewhere. They get to a bridge. Maybe it is broken? It looks like all is lost. Then the boy reaches down, and greenery starts blossoming all over the bridge proving that he is the chosen one after all. Or something like that.
Extras: I am pretty sure that it wasn't written by anyone famous at the time (they may be famous now). I was just going to the library every day and reading whatever happened to be around that was science fiction-y or fantasy, so it wasn't something I had heard of.

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28449207-strange-the-dreamer?

This question is surprisingly tropey. I keep finding likely candidates but nothing that matches everything... :-)

Thanks, @Valorum, but it is not Strange the Dreamer, which was written in 2017.
